# Replace string into another string

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace

I have a string, part of which looks like this:

```
"..devices=233.423.423.553&..."
```

and I'd like to replace the values of "devices=" with different values like "111.111" so it would appear like:

```
"..devices=111.111&..."
```

I think I can do that with some sort of expressions since I need to do that inline.Any trick would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a relative noob, so forgive me if this is completely inefficient, but how about:

```
var myStr="..devices=233.423.423.553&..."
var something=myStr.substring((myStr.indexOf("=")+1),(myStr.indexOf("&")));
myStr.replace(something,"111.111.111");
```

Using regular expressions looks cooler, though.

Comment: Looks like only pure javascript worked to my goal. all expressions of lennon626, hsz and h2ooooooo didn't worked.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.. Just replace with the string you want to replace with:

```
var str = '..devices=233.423.423.553&...';
str = str.replace(/devices=[0-9.]+/g, 'devices=111.111');

console.log(str); //..devices=111.111&...
```

**Autopsy:**

- `devices=` *the literal string `devices=`*
- `[0-9.]+` *the digits `0` to `9` or the literal character `.` matched 1 to infinity times*
- `/g` *means "global". Will replace **any** occurence rather than just the first one*

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
 "..devices=233.423.423.553&...".replace(/(devices)=(?:\d+(\.\d+)*)/, '$1=111.111')
```